# Mapping of a source file from fat file in Informatica designer

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

**My source File Description:**
In creating a mapping in Informatica designer where in my source is a fat 
file which is the collection of different types of data, as in customer 
details from customer table, his enrollment details from enrollment table
and few more tables like this.

In this scenario how do I proceed in creating
mapping and transformation to target?
If it were a single source file I define a simple source and target mapping.

Comment: How about splitting the file first? Using a shell script or a dedicated mapping? Can you post a sample file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a mapping with one source and multiple targets connecting all the ports to their corresponding targets. This way you'd read the source once and populate all targets at the same time. This however assumes that no other processing is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a required tables as a source. Use joiner transformation to join them together and map them to the target if in case any condition is to be applied between the tables.
You can have multiple sources and connect them to a single source qualifier and map it to the target.